# rails-jquery-autocomplete and acts_as_taggable form routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

Acts_as_taggable is working correctly. I did the following to add [rails-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete) to my webapp. I am using Rails 4.2.2/Heroku in production.

```
add gem 'rails-jquery-autocomplete' to gem file
bundle install
heroku run bundle install

updated my application.js file to 

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

and pushed to Heroku

// Model
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
end

// Controller
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :tag, :name, :class_name => 'ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag'
  ...
private
  def photo_params
    params.require(:photo).permit(:picture, :title, :tag_list)
  end
end

// Routes
get 'tags/:tag', to: 'photos#index', as: :tag
resources :photos do
    get :autocomplete_tag_name, :on => :collection
end

//View  

<% form_for :photo, url: photos_path, html: {multipart: true } do |form| %>
  <%= f.file_field :picture %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %> 
  <%= form.label :tag_list, "Tags" %>
  <%= form.autocomplete_field :tag_list, autocomplete_tag_name_photos_path, :"data-delimiter" => ', ' %>
<% end %>
```

The form saves and the tags and photo are added to the database but the auto-complete does not work at all.

I have been through [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486745/rails-autocomplete-tags-separated-by-commas-using-regex/6687895#6687895) [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937185/how-to-add-tagging-with-autocomplete-to-an-existing-model-in-rails) but they have not helped me find the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your nice post.

I have success show the autocomplete tag, but have a problem when I go to click submit button, for create new or edit, it did nothing. And button seems change to disable style.

On log, only show the last status from GET autocomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add gem 'jquery-ui-rails'.